# NGINX Drupal Redirect for Mobile

Tags: nginx, regex, drupal

**What I want to do**;

I want mobile users to be redirected to http://m.site.org/mobile-home.

Being redirected to the m.bzaeds.org isn't an issue. I also have this working fine in Apache, but the same .htaccess rule I have in apache doesn't seem to be working in NGINX. I also tried to convert this exact rule using an NGINX translator, but the rule it gave me did not work either.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} m.site.org
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mobile-home [L]
```

**What I've done so far**;

So, I have NGINX redirecting to m.site.here/mobile-home. Now, we use a Mobile module that detects if the device connected is a mobile device and automatically applies a custom mobile theme. It is detecting with no issues if a device is a mobile device.

However, it fails to load even though the redirection is working and I looked in the error_log and noticed it was failing because /var/www/html/drupal/mobile-home didn't exist -- which, yes, is true. I'm assuming this has something to do with mobile-home actually being a node, because that's what pages are in drupal.

However, no matter how I tried to create the redirect (or return 301), it either was forbidden, infinite redirect loop of doom, or threw me the aforementioned error.

Any ideas?

Now here is a plethora of confusion that I've tried so far;

```
    location / {
            #if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPhone|iPod|android|blackberry)') {
    #   rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    #}
            #if ($http_host ~ "m.bzaeds.org"){
            #rewrite ^(.*)$ /mobile-home [L] RewriteCond $request_filename !-f;
            #}
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
    #try_files $uri /mobile-home break;
}        


    location @rewrite {
        #index index.php;
    #   if ($http_user_agent ~* ('iPhone|iPod)') {
    #     rewrite ^(.*)$/index.php http://m.bzaeds.org/mobile-home$1 break;
    #   }
        # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
            # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    #return 301 /mobile-home break;
```

(And, I've also tried getting rid of location @rewrite and just doing the main rewrite under location / , but I still got many of the same errors. I just had done this statement like this in my non-mobile version, so, mmyes.)

Comment: Honestly, this question doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Could you simplify this to (a) what you've got and (b) what it should do that it doesn't?

Comment: I basically have nothing. Nothing I've done works. All I could post is what I've tried. I have a Drupal Site, and a page called /mobile-home exists. All I want is when a user on an iPhone or iPad or Android phone connects to the site, I want them to be redirected to the /mobile-home . However, my statements have done that and redirected to m.site.org/mobile-home, but it fails and the error log says /var/www/html/drupal/mobile-home doesn't exist. Which, again, true, and  figure this correlates to it being Drupal.

Comment: so what i understand: you want mobile-users, who accesses www.site.org, beeing redirected to m.site.org/mobile-home, right? mobile-detetcion is done by UA, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't do this they way I ultimately wanted to with redirection because no matter what I tried it still wouldn't stop looking in the wrong place. However, I did discover that if you are using the module "Mobile Tools" it gives you the option under "Front Page" to set it to a node, in our case, mobile-home rather than index.

Problem fixed, problem solved, good enough.